# Returning index of list with greatest value

Tags: python

```
def findMaxDiff(l):
    'list(list(int)), returns index of the row with the maximum difference between elements and the value of the difference in that row'
    return (max(max(a) - min(a) for a in l), l.index(max(l, key=max)))
```

While I've gotten it to return the value of the maximum number, I can't quite get it to return the correct index of that list. It works fine in this case:

```
>>> findMaxDiff([[12,3,50,17], [10,5,9,100,31], [5,3,1]])
    (95, 1)
```

But doesn't in this case.

```
>>> findMaxDiff([[0,10],[99,99]])
    (10, 1)
>>> findMaxDiff([[1],[2],[3]])
    (0, 2)
```

For the first one it should return (10,0), and the second should return (0,0). I've tried key=sum and key=max, but both return the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this:

```
def thing(list_):                                  
  temp = enumerate(max(x) - min(x) for x in list_)
  return max(x[::-1] for x in temp)
```

Comment: This worked in returning (10,0), but strangely still returns (0,2).

Comment: Well, it's a three way tie for the last case.  I don't see how (0, 0) is any more correct than (0, 2) in that example.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll just change the code to this, since it does eliminate that (10,1) issue and everything else works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you really want (0, 0) for the last case you could change the last line to `return max(l_, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: @wim: You can only use `enumerate` 5 times a day on SO!